# How Can I Access Locally Hosted IIS WebSite from Remote Computer By My IP Address?

Tags: asp.net, iis

How Can I Access My Locally Hosted IIS WebSite from Remote Computer By My IP Address ?

Comment: is it static public ip address?

Answer (score 2):

You have to [check you ip here](http://www.whatismyip.com/),  make sure that you are [forwarding port 80](http://portforward.com/) (especially if you're in a locale home network), and then you could access your server by `http://<server_ip>` e.g. `http://192.168.0.6`

Note that as long as you don't have a fixed (static) ip, your ip address might change, and you'll have to recheck it.

Another note- The default HTTP port is 80, and by using port 80 you could access your server via browsers without writing the port number. If for any reason you like to switch port, make sure your forward that port number and access your site by `http://<server_ip>:<port_number>` , e.g. `http://192.168.0.6:8080`

Comment: Provided its in your local network , or your machine shud have a static ip.

Comment: Also the port isn't important . It can be any port which may it be hosted on.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using some other port. then you can go with `http://<ip_address>:<port_no>`

Comment: are you getting IIS page on just giving http://<ip_address>:<port_no> ? . you need to set the static ip address. Refer this link :- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx